I'm getting TemplateInputException for my HTML file in springboot
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [Kredit-bee-invoice], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolversenter image description here
I tried to generate invoice from template in resource folder unexpectedly I'm getting exception so I tried the below things but nothing worked for me
#Template Configuration
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

<resources>
    <resource>
       <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
       <includes>
          <include>application.properties</include>
       </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>


I'm not sure, the error says that the first letter in the file is uppercase. But the file itself (judging by the image) starts with lower case.
Kredit-bee-invoice -> kredit-bee-invoice
